# Where can I find example charts for scrum development?

Tags: scrum

Where can I find example charts for scrum development?

For example: Burn down or backlog charts.

Answer (score 2):

I always find the ScrumForTeamSystem process guidance as the place to go for reference for anything scrum like:

http://scrumforteamsystem.com/processguidance/v2/ProcessGuidance.aspx

A sprint burndown chart when things are going as they should be will be a nice linear graph towards the zero:

http://scrumforteamsystem.com/processguidance/v2/Images/SBBurndown.html

And a product backlog should look like a nice clearly prioritized list of user stories delivered by your product owner on which you can give high level estimates and use as a basis for creating small development work items otherwise know as sprint backlog items:

http://scrumforteamsystem.com/processguidance/v2/Artefacts/ProductBacklog/ProductBacklogContents.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Cohn has a good example of the burndown chart on [his blog](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/resources/5-sample-burndown-tracking-excel-sheet-for-scrumxp).  I find his writing style succinct and concise.

In particular I like his [alternate burndown chart](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/scrum/alt-releaseburndown), which tracks the work completed by the team on the positive y-axis and the new work added/re-scoped on the negative y-axis.  By using the trends of the work completed and work added will give you a reasonable guesstimate of the project's end date.